# mongodb get avg of array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongodb with 200000 documents like this one

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"a" : [ 
    {
        "a1" : 9,
        "a2" : 88,
        "a3" : 70
    }
],
"date" : ISODate("2007-09-11T02:17:39.543Z"),
"b" : [ 
    {
        "b1" : 4,
        "b2" : 10
    }
],
 "c" : 2,
}
```

I have to group by hour and by b, then sort by hour. And then output to collection with following structure for every element of a: hour, b and avg of a1.

The following mongo query works but is groups on c, not b.

```
db.test.aggregate
([
{$unwind: "$a"},
{
    $group:
    {'_id': {hours:{'$hour':'$date'}, 'c':'$c'},'AVG_parameter':{$avg: "a.a1"}}},
{$sort:{'_id.hours':1}},
{$project:{hours:1, 'c':1,'AVG_parameter':1}}
])
```

When i try to group by hour and b, the avg_parameter stays 0.

Comment: What do you mean by grouping on `b`? Grouping on the pair `(b1, b2)`?

Comment: Yes, i have grouped it by b1 and b2